# [abilities], [skills], [talents], [feats], [perks] and the like into [character-capabilities]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'd like to request that tags referring to a character's in-game capabilities ([skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skills), [abilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abilities), [perks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perks), [spells](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells)) rolled into [character-capabilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-capabilities). I'd like a broader tag because it is very game specific whether something a character is capable of is a feat, ability, skill, talent, spell or perk; so I feel that [character-capabilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-capabilities) covers all these bases.

This is *not* for character stats though!

Comment: I agree that there's room to merge, I'm not sure `character-abilities` is the best ultimate target.

Comment: @raven-dreamer D'oh, another typo!

Comment: @RavenDreamer I have corrected it, the proposal now reads [tag:character-capabilities]

Comment: Any reason you want that instead of the `character-build` tag we already have?

Comment: I hadn't seen that tag when I was considering this.

Comment: I'd rather not have the tags at all, but if we're going to have them, I'd be very careful about merging this many tags -  yes, they are all often used synonymously, but not always -  which, quite frankly, is why I'd rather not have the tags at all.